# adding fading effect in facebook fanpage

Tags: javascript, facebook, fbml, facebook-page

I was wondering how this (http://www.facebook.com/Sennheiser) was done in facebook fanpage? It has a fading slider/gallery. Any good links or tutorials that talks about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook provides [FBJS animation library](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/fbjs/#animation). Sennheiser is most likely implemented with that. However since application tabs now support iframes you can just use normal HTML and any JavaScript library you wish. [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is popular option.